# HTML Form File Uploads doesn't upload file

Tags: html, file, upload, forms

Files doesn't get uploaded though all back-end code is correct. I tested the back end code with another front-end styled code and it worked fine.

but in my front end code it doesn't upload any files. I removed all css and scripts as well to figure out the issue.

here is my simple front end HTML form :

```
<form action="upload_handler.php" method="post">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you forgot to mention the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="upload_handler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is with the attributes in your `<form>` tag. To successfully enable files to be uploaded properly in HTML, following requirements should be there.

- Make sure that the form uses method="post"
- The form also needs the following attribute: enctype="multipart/form-data".

**It specifies which content-type to use when submitting the form**

So just add this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part inside your `<form>` tag.

Comment: I've added both of these things and the .files field is still undefined for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons why your HTML form file uploads might not be working. Here are some of the most common ones:

- The form is not using the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.
  This attribute tells the browser to encode the form data in a way
  that allows files to be uploaded.
- The file input element does not have a `name` attribute. This attribute
  is used to identify the file in the form data.
- The file that you are trying to upload is too large.
- The maximum file size that can be uploaded is typically limited by the server configuration.
- The file that you are trying to upload is not a valid file type. The
  server may only allow certain file types to be uploaded.
- There is an error in the server-side code that is responsible for
  processing the file upload.

If you have checked all of these things and your file uploads are still not working, then you may need to contact your web hosting provider for assistance.

Here are some additional things you can check:

- Make sure that the file input element has the `accept` attribute set to the file types that you want to allow. For example, to allow only JPEG and PNG images, you would set the `accept` attribute to `image/jpeg`, `image/png`.
- Make sure that the file that you are trying to upload is in the same directory as the HTML form. If the file is in a different directory, you will need to specify the full path to the file in the `file` attribute of the file input element.
- Make sure that the server has the correct permissions set for the directory where the file is being uploaded. The directory must be writable by the web server user.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion: it is possible that your `htaccess` codes could be preventing file uploads. Here are a few things you can check:

- Make sure that the `AllowOverride` directive in your `htaccess` file is
  set to `All`. This will allow all .htaccess directives to be applied.
- Make sure that the `Require all granted` directive is not present in
  your `htaccess` file. This directive will deny all file uploads.
- If you have any other directives in your `htaccess` file that restrict
  access to files, make sure that they are not preventing file uploads.

If you have checked all of these things and your file uploads are still not working, then you may need to contact your web hosting provider for assistance.

Here are some additional things you can do to troubleshoot your `htaccess` file:

- Try disabling your `htaccess` file by renaming it to
  `.htaccess.disabled`. This will temporarily disable all of the
  directives in your `htaccess` file. If file uploads start working after
  you disable your `htaccess` file, then you know that the problem is
  with your `htaccess` file.
- Try copying your `htaccess` file from a working website. This will give
  you a known-good `htaccess` file that you can use as a starting point.
- If you are still having trouble, then you may need to contact your
  web hosting provider for assistance. They will be able to help you
  troubleshoot your `htaccess` file and fix the problem.