# Upload Image form PHP

Tags: php

Warning: Undefined array key "img" in C:\xampp\htdocs\UplodeImg\up.php on line 10

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\UplodeImg\up.php on line 10

````
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "up";
$password = "MohamedHasan";
$dbname = "up";

$connected = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($_POST){ 
    
       echo $loc = $_FILES['img']['name'];

   }

?>

<form class="form_sign addPro content_6 formAdd" method="post">
        <label>upload img</label>
        <input type="file" name="img">
        <br>
        <button class="col-3" name="add">add</button>
</form>```
````

Comment: `$_POST` will always exist since it's a super global. You want to check to see if it contains keys, specifically if it contains the `img` key

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984907/html-form-file-uploads-doesnt-upload-file, the `enctype` attribute is missing.